# IBM BPM delay on load event

Tags: websphere, settimeout, onload, ibm-bpm, spark-ui

I want to make a button click after 10 seconds when the UI loads. I've tried below code in the "On load" event, but seems that the timer doesn't work:

`function myFunction() {`

`me.click(); }`

`setTimeout(myFunction, 10000);`

Any ideas how to trigger the timer in "On load" event?

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like below.
1.Call buttonClick() function on OnLoadEvent.

```
buttonClick(){
 setTimeout(page.ui.get(<Control Name>).click(),10000)
}
```

OR

```
window.load(){
 setTimeout(function myFunction() {
 page.ui.get(<Control Name>).click()},10000)
}
```